# C++ array (Beginner)

Tags: c++, arrays

I misstook arrays for vectors, Sorry (array is vektor in swedish)

I would need some help with a program I'm making. It is a assignment so I really need to understand how I do this and not just get the code :P

I need to make a array containing 10 "numbers" (I would like to make them editable when the program is running).
After I'v done this I need to make the program calculate the "average value" of all the numbers "/

Would be pretty neat if you could pick how many numbers you wanted the average value of as well, if anyone could share some knowledge in how I should to that :P
Anyways, I'v tried some code to make the vector that didn't work, I might as well add it here:

```
int vector[10];
```

and
    vector[0] "number 1: ";
and so on for the input of numbers in the vector.

```
int sum = vector[0] + vector[1] + ...
cout << "average value is: " << sum/5;
```

should work for getting the average value though (right?)

I should allso  add:

```
float average(int v[], int n)
```

to this thing as well, can't really se how though.

Any help/knowledge at all would be awesome! Cheers.

Comment: start with an implementation of `average()` which returns the average of an array with length 1 (`n=1`).

Comment: I would not name any variable `vector` since it is a name in `namespace std`, especially since you seem to be using `using namespace std;` (which often is a bad idea).

Comment: Are you trying to do this using the std::vector or an array?

Comment: I pretty much have no idéa how to do this "/
according to the book int temp[5]; should create a vector with 5 values. I will name it v then "/ could do without namespace std; then?
I have not even learnt what a array is and std::vector is unknown to me as well :c

Comment: It doesn't create a vector with five values.  It creates a raw array with five values.  A "vector" is a different type of container.  What book are you using, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function like following would work for computing average of an array containing n elements.

```
float average(int v[], int n)
{
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
       sum += v[i]; //sum all the numbers in the vector v
    }

    return sum / n;
}
```

You can declare your array as you have done however i do recommend you to name it something else then vector to avoid confusion. About tour issue with changing the numbers in the array you can do this by for example maning a loop going from one to 10 and then make the user enter values for all the fields.

Vektor på svenska = array på engelska (vector är något annat :))

Answer (score 2):

To pick how many numbers you wanted to average:

Native: (G++/Clang) only, not "legal" C++

```
cin >> num;
int vector[num];
```

"Correct" native (pointers):

```
int *vector = new int [num];
```

"Proper" C++:

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<int> v(num);
```

Comment: So for visual studio 2013 I should use:
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector> // To add the ability to even use vectors at     all:
    std::vector<int> v(10); // What is std for here? would float work as well?:

Comment: 2nd or 3rd, they are all fine, though I would recommend the third one

Comment: Using `float` or `int` depends on whether the user should be able to enter numbers  with decimals (then use `float` or `double`) or not (then `int` is completly fine - at least for the input).

Comment: aha, yeah. so I could use double? it would work as int with numbers like 6,7,3?

Comment: Yes. When your vector stores `int` then the user just can enter ...-1, 0,1,2,... But when you use `float` or `double` the user can enter ...,-1,0,1,2,... but additionally also numbers like 1.2 or -4.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want exactly 10 numbers, you can eliminate a lot of overhead by simply using an array.  However, assuming you want to use a vector, you can easily find the average taking advantage of its "size" member, as such:

```
float average(std::vector<int> nums)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++)
        sum += nums[i];
    return sum / nums.size();
}
```

Note that this does assume the sum won't be higher than 2^31-1, IE the highest number a signed integer can represent.  To be safer you could use an unsigned and/or 64 bit int for sum, or some arbitrary precision library like gmp, but I'd assume that is all outside the scope of your assignment.

Comment: I misstook vector for arrays :c sorry, but now I learnt what a vector is so I guess that is something! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must declare and array of size 10, which you have done.

Use a loop to get ten inputs from the user.
(`for` or `while` loops would do)

Use another loop to calculate the sum of all ten numbers and store it in a variable.

Divide the variable by ten.

This is what you need to do essentially. But, to make your driver program prettier, you can define the following functions:

`void GetInput(int *A);   //put the input loop here`

You can also write any one of the given two functions:

```
long Sum(int * A)   //put the summing loop here

double Average(int * A)  //put the summing loop here AND divide the sum by ten
```

Since you are a beginner I feel obliged to tell you that you don't need to return an array since it isalways passed as a reference parameter. I did not bother to pass the array size as a parameter to any functions because that is fixed and known to be 10 but it will be good practice to do that.

Comment: Sorry but I can sadly not understand much of that "/ in the worthless book I should get this knowledge is tells me that int n[10]; should work to make a array.. But it doesent

Comment: As for book, go for Deitel and Deitel.
You can also consult, learncpp.com.
The slashes represent comments, comments are not executed as program statements, they are ignored by the compiler

Comment: `int n[10]`
does make an array. But you will need to initialize it with numbers. If you are new then I should also tell you that this statement makes an array of size ten with indeces ranging from 0 to 9 inclusive. You need to store integers in the array for it to give you a reasonable output